# Making Bublebee NOT work

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, steam, bumblebee

I have laptop with Optimus, and with Bumblebee properly installed. I want to play Dota 2 and my Nvidia card apparently hates it, to the point of no repair. I tried everything I managed to find, even the specific fix (with setting -nod3d9ex as launch options on Steam) and still no success. The thing is, it worked when I was using Windows 7 with bugged Optimus, always choosing Intel integrated card, so I know it works on it. My question is: is there a config file somewhere that I can use to make Bumblebee NOT activate Nvidia for a specific program? I'm pretty sure that would fix my problem.

(also if you ever consider buying anything Nvidia related for the love of God, DON'T DO IT)

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia support for Linux is actually terrible, my first laptop with Nvidia optimus made me lose 1 week to properly install the first version of bumblebee.
Bumblebee only runs a program if you ask it to, with the optirun or primusrun. 
You can uninstall bumblebee and install it easily again, but I don't think there is a way to disable it since you need to call it to use. (I could not comment due to small reputation)

Comment: Actually, Bumblebee has a config (don't remember where) when it should turn on, and in the guide I read, the guy wrote to change turn on and turn off moments, from requested to actually detecting if you need it. I know it's working, because the problem I have is Nvidia-specific, I didn't have it when using Intel integrated card on Windows 7 like a month ago.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch

Comment: Thank you, this is both useful and simple. Not exactly what I was searching for, but will work anyways.